# What IC is branded H1U?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I couldn't find any information on this IC. What is it?

[image]

Comment: It’s from Analog Devices, from the logo.  What type of circuit is it in, and can you measure the pin pitch?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that and this is from an electrosurgical unit

Comment: Since this is clearly an AD part, you could also just ask this to their tech support.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's an [Analog Devices ADA4891-2ARMZ](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201141930_Analog-Devices-ADA4891-2ARZ_C1347482.pdf) amplifier.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Operational-Amplifier_Analog-Devices-ADA4891-2ARMZ-R7_C143927.html))

Comment: Do you know anything that can replace it and has the same spec ? sorry to bother you too much

Comment: @Angelina Well, why not replace it with the same part? It's [readily available](https://octopart.com/search?q=ADA4891-2ARMZ&currency=USD&specs=0) at all major suppliers.

Comment: It is kind of an emergency and suppliers in my area won't deliver fast enough and AD is hard to come by

Comment: @Angelina Without knowing anything about the rest of the circuit, it's impossible to give informed suggestions. Also, trying to repair medical equipment without (assumably) much knowledge about electronics sounds like a bad idea to say the least.

Comment: @Angelina You don't say where you are located. If you are in the US, Digikey can often get the part shipped the same day (call and talk to a person and explain the situation for best results) and you can have the part early morning the next day.

Comment: @Angelina If's medial equipment do you have a list of approved suppliers with the required quality traceability you must use?